# Dealing with NaN using imputer in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nan

I am trying to clean my dataset using python. I am using the imputer from scikit learn for it. My dataset is a csv file that contains a lot of 'NULL' values. On importing the data using from_csv of panda library and converting that dataframe to a matrix my data looks like:

```
[1 '2013-04-04 08:32:15' 12 187 nan nan 219 10404 4 4.0 1 2.2 0.0149 5.03
 26 170.74 0 23246 1 0 4 0 1 1 nan nan 1 nan nan nan nan nan nan 0.0 0.0
 nan nan nan nan 0.0 1.0 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan 0.0 0.0 nan 0 nan 0]
```

However now when I try using the imputer it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myRandomForesy.py", line 27, in <module>
    temp[i] = imp.transform(temp[i])
  File "/Users/Sherlock/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/imputation.py", line 331, in transform
    self.axis)
  File "/Users/Sherlock/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/imputation.py", line 252, in _dense_fit
    mask = _get_mask(X, missing_values)
  File "/Users/Sherlock/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/imputation.py", line 30, in _get_mask
    if value_to_mask == "NaN" or np.isnan(value_to_mask):
TypeError: Not implemented for this type
```

Here is a snippet of my code

```
imp = Imputer(missing_values="nan",strategy='mean',axis=1)
while i<len(temp):
    imp=imp.fit(temp[i])
    temp[i] = imp.transform(temp[i])
    test_temp[i] = imp.transform(test_temp[i])
    i+=1
```

Comment: Replace `nan` with `NaN`

Comment: I'm trying understand your data. Is your example a single row? Are you trying to iterate over each element? The Imputer works over a column or row vector of numeric types.

Comment: It worked. Thanks Barmaley.exe

Comment: @Barmaley.exe - Do you want to turn your comment into an answer? - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is quite old, but just for people with the same issue, you replace

"nan" in imp = Imputer(missing_values="nan",strategy='mean',axis=1)

with

np.nan

because the nan value in the data is actual nan values, rather than a string